# AJAX call is not working as expected

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send form data using ajax. But there's an error in ajax operation and only "error" callback function is executed. 
Here's what I tried:

```
$("#issue_submit").click(function (e) {

    console.log("clicked on the issue submit");
    e.preventDefault();

    // Validate the form
    var procurementForm = $("#it_procuremet_form");

    if($(procurementForm).valid()===false){
        return false;
    }

    // Show ajax loader
    appendData();

    var formData = $(procurementForm).serialize();

    // Send request to save the records through ajax
    var formRequest = $.ajax({
        url: app.baseurl("itprocurement/save"),
        data: formData,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json"
    });

    formRequest.done(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    });


    formRequest.error(function (res, err) {
        console.log(res);
    });


    formRequest.always(function () {
        $("#overlay-procurement").remove();
        // do somethings that always needs to occur regardless of error or success
    });

});
```

Routes are defined as:

```
$f3->route('POST /itprocurement/save', 'GBD\Internals\Controllers\ITProcurementController->save');
```

Also I added :

```
$f3->route('POST /itprocurement/save [ajax]', 'GBD\Internals\Controllers\ITProcurementController->save');
```

I tried returning a simple string to the ajax call at the controller class.
`ITProcurementController.php` :

```
public function save($f3)
{
    echo 'Problem!';
    return;
    $post = $f3->get('POST');
}
```

But only 'error' callback is executed. I cannot locate what is wrong. Please Help.

Comment: When you do the request, have the network tab open in the developer tools in chrome or firefox and let us know what response you are getting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are specifying that you expect json back:

```
// Send request to save the records through ajax
var formRequest = $.ajax({
    url: app.baseurl("itprocurement/save"),
    data: formData,
    type: "POST",
    // Here you specify that you expect json back:
    dataType: "json"
});
```

What you send back is not json:

```
echo 'Problem!';
return;
```

This is an unquoted string, which is not valid json.

To send valid json back, you would need:

```
echo json_encode('Problem!');
return;
```

You could also remove the `dataType` attribute, depending on your needs.